# View information that exists only in the inheritance class

Tags: typescript

Hello I'm new in the Software world and I have a problem, I want to display variable that exists only in the derived class.
This is the parent class:

```
abstract class A {
  public x: number;
}
```

The derived class:

```
// class B extends A {
  public y: number;
}
```

I want to show my variable `y` from the main but I can't go to him, how I do it?
If I have an array, type A:

```
var examples: A[] = new Array<A>;
```

How can I get the `y` variable?

Answer (score 0):

Welcome Marko ,

In typescript you can run on the array in a loop ,

and use `instanceof` when you the loop identify the type B you can get the variables that exist in this class :

Use this code :

```
    for (const item of examples ) { // Run on the array you created
if (item instanceof B) {
// Here you will have access to all variables in the class
document.write ("Y value : " item.y);
}
```